# Is the Last-Modified HTTP header required for browser caching?

Tags: http-headers

When I unset the `Last-Modified` header in Apache (`ETags` are also disabled), Firefox (4.01) will not cache any file *regardless* of whether I set a future `Expires` header or enable the `Cache-Control` header.

So is the `Last-Modified` (and/or an `ETag`) header required for browser caching?

From [here](http://www.mnot.net/blog/2009/02/24/unintended_caching):

> If no validator (an ETag or
>   Last-Modified header) is present on a
>   response, and it doesn’t have any
>   explicit freshness information, it
>   will be considered uncacheable.

... well, if by "Freshness Information" they mean "Cache-Control" or "Expires" header, Firefox should be caching without the Last-Modified header.

**EDIT FOR FURTHER FIREFOX INFO**

Note that no attempt to generate a 304 on any PHP file served by Apache 2.2 in Firefox 4.01 is successful (reload, fresh visit, etc.) without a `Last-Modified` header, regardless of any combination being set of a valid caching `Cache-Control` header, the `Expires` header or both headers.

`foo.php`: content of this file simply echoes 'Hello World'.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Mon, 06 Jun 2011 14:04:58 GMT
Server: Apache
Cache-Control: public, max-age=3600
Expires: Fri, 01 Jul 2011 21:23:55 GMT
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 1594
Keep-Alive: timeout=10, max=500
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
```

**EDIT FOR EVEN MORE STRANGE FIREFOX 4.01 FINDINGS**

Even stranger, based on what I've seen with Firefox 4.01, no form of server-side cache control headers (Expires and/or Cache-Control) influence Firefox's caching behavior. Firefox only cares about Freshness information (Etag or Last-Modified).

In summary, if the file has been modified, Firefox reloads it, regardless of any Expires or Cache-Control headers. If the file doesn't contain any Freshness information, Firefox reloads it no matter what.

If anyone finds out differently in their observations, please update me.

**ANOTHER EDIT**

From [this link](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec13.html):

> 13.2.1 Server-Specified Expiration
>
> An expiration time cannot be used to
>   force a user agent to refresh its
>   display or reload a resource; its
>   semantics apply only to caching
>   mechanisms, and such mechanisms need
>   only check a resource's expiration
>   status when a new request for that
>   resource is initiated. See section
>   13.13 for an explanation of the difference between caches and history
>   mechanisms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be wary of reading random articles on the net (although Mark Nottingham's stuff is usually sensible). The definitive source should always by the RFCs. And according to [RFC 2616](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt) a browser should cache a document with an Expires: header where the timestamp is in the future, or where other valid caching instructions are provided provided that the document is not returned in response to a POST request.

It's perfectly valid to set a max-age without a last-modified - and the spec explicitly addresses that.

Certainly what you describe seems very unusual and implies that FF4.01 will never cache content - I would be amazed that it passed the QC checks with such a glaring omission. Can you provide details of the requests and responses proving this (e.g. with [liveheaders](http://livehttpheaders.mozdev.org/screenshots.html))?

Comment: Sure, see my edit above. I just re-re-re-tested and my info is accurate.

Answer (score 0):

It varies across browsers as to exactly what is needed, but generally I work using the theory that if content is going to be cached properly it needs at least a Last-Modified **&** Etag header, Expires is a plus but if it has an etag the browser will generally prioritize that over anything else.

Comment: I appreciate the feedback. From what I gather, ETags aren't always compatible under certain circumstances (CDN's, etc.). Do you happen to know if the Last-Modified header is actually required for proper caching? My experience says it is, but maybe I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: I don't think it's required, but it's recommended. If you want total un-cachability set Expires to in the past and Last-modified to in the future (It doesn't sound logical that something can be modified in the future, but browsers will just say 'Is the Last-modified date higher than the last time I accessed this content'.) If you want total cachability set last modified to a long time in the past, and expires to a long time in the future. Adding ETags is a plus, as are correct Pragma headers. Any browsers/clients that don't support any of the headers will just ignore them